# random forest gets worse as number of trees increases

Tags: r, classification, random-forest

I am running into difficulties when using `randomForest` (in R) for a classification problem. My R code, an image, and data are here:
http://www.psy.plymouth.ac.uk/research/Wsimpson/data.zip
The observer is presented with either a faint image (contrast=`con`) buried in noise or just noise on each trial. He rates his confidence (`rating`) that the face is present. I have categorised `rating` to be a yes/no judgement (`y`). The face is either inverted (`invert=1`) or not in each block of 100 trials (one file). I use the contrast (1st column of predictor matrix `x`) and the pixels (the rest of the columns) to predict `y`.

It is critical to my application that I have an "importance image" at the end which shows how much each pixel contributes to the decision `y`. I have 1000 trials (length of `y`) and 4248 pixels+contrast=4249 predictors (ncols of `x`). Using `glmnet` (logistic ridge regression) on this problem works fine

`fit<-cv.glmnet(x,y,family="binomial",alpha=0)`

However `randomForest` does not work at all,

`fit <- randomForest(x=x, y=y, ntree=100)`

and it gets *worse* as the number of trees increases. For `invert=1`, the classification error for `randomForest` is 34.3%, and for `glmnet` it is 8.9%.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong with `randomForest`, and how to fix it.

Comment: One thing to note is that the reported error rate for randomForest is a genuine out-of-sample figure, whereas that for cv.glmnet is not. cv.glmnet is a tool for finding the best value of lambda (and, with a bit of coding, alpha as well), but the error will be optimistic. You should split your data into actual training and validation sets to get a useful comparison between the two methods.

Comment: Thanks, that's a helpful point, Hong Ooi. I was curious about the fact that the classification error is lowest for the smallest number of trees and it grows as the number of trees grows. I have looked, but not seen any mention of that anywhere. It seems very odd.

Comment: this question is probably more suited for cross-validated http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: ok thanks Stas I will post there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ridge regression's only parameter lambda is chosen via internal cross-validation in `cv.glmnet`, as pointed out by Hong Ooi. and the error rate you get out of `cv.glmnet` realtes to that. `randomForest` gives you OOB error that is akin to an error on a dedicated test set (which is what you are interested in).

`randomForest` requires you to calibrate it manually (i.e. have a dedicated validation set to see which parameters work best) and there are a few to consider: depth of the trees (via fixing the number of examples in each node or the number of nodes), number of randomly chosen attributes considered at each split and the number of trees. you can use `tuneRF` to find the optimal number of `mtry`.

when evaluated on the train set, the more trees you add the better your predictions get. however, you will see predictive ability on a test set starts diminishing after a certain number of trees are grown -- this is due to overfitting. `randomForest` determines the optimal number of trees via OOB error estimates or, if you provide it, by using the test set. if `rf.mod` is your fitted RF model then `plot(rf.mod)` will allow you to see at which point roughly it starts to overfit. when using the `predict` function on a fitted RF it will use the optimal number of trees.

in short, you are not comparing the two models' performances correctly (as pointed out by Hong Ooi) and also your parameters might be off and/or you might be overfitting (although unlikely with just 100 trees).

Comment: Thanks very much stas. Essentially, randomForest performs best with one tree, and it's downhill all the way from there (as trees increase)! Very odd.

Comment: have you tried `rpart`? (regression/classification trees package). but this does sound odd -- ensemble methods usually work extremely well and i struggle to imagine why adding more trees on top of just one would hurt predictive ability. but it is hard to say more without knowing more about the data.

Comment: stas, I have given a link and you can download the data if you would like to see them and play with them. Let me say that these data are very regular indeed and if I were to ignore all the pixels and just do an ordinary logistic regression with con as the predictor, the fit is extremely good. The results with glmnet are exactly as I would expect, with the pixel importances being as expected. I have another method for calculating pixel importances (not in the classification literature but from my specialised vision area), and it agrees excellently with the glmnet solution.